# Modify razor Layout outside the view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a view inside the shared folder and I'm using it in several area's. The problem I face now is that the layout from the _viewstart.cshtml of the area isn't applied.

I've also tried a seperate layout injector (code below) that I've used in MVC4, but the problem with the injector is that MasterName isn't available any more.

```
public class LayoutInjecterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = "<layout>"
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is there a way to modify the Layout variable outside of the view so that I can apply different layouts to a shared view?

Edit: I've a cascading layout system inside my area's. So the layout pages in the _viewstarts in the area's point to a master layout in the base shared folder.

**Shared layout in manage area (_manageLayout.cshtml), referenced in the _viewstart.cshtml**

```
@{
   Layout = "_baseLayout"
}
<htmlstuff>
    @renderbody()
</htmlstuff>
```

**Shared base layout (_baseLayout.cshtml)**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML STUFF -->
    @renderbody()
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source code of the [RazorViewEngine](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2e2784aa3d2a2abead5d3366714ddcc4cd63f14f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngine.cs) you can see that on line 416 it states that it loads the ViewStartPage based on the relative path of the view. Since your view is in the root view folder the root ViewStart is loaded and thus is the Layout of the root loaded, and not the area layout even if you are actually in an area.

You could override it as follows:

**~/Views/Shared/TestSharedRoot.cshtml**

```
@{
    if (ViewData.ContainsKey("_MasterLayout"))
    {
        Layout = ViewData["_MasterLayout"] as string;
    }
}
//...
```

**~/Areas/Manage/Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    ViewData["_MasterLayout"] = "_ManageLayout";
    return View("TestSharedRoot");
}
```

Now the `Test` action will show the root view with the manage layout, and when called from the root controllers it will simply show the default layout.

Answer (score -2):

Below way is not exactly answer of your question, but it may be helpful.

- Create a shared view for each area.
- Use partial view or view component to render actual shared view in
  the area's shared view.
- Use area's shared view in the action.

Area example:

`_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "_AreaLayout";
}
```

`_SharedView.cshtml`:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SharedView.cshtml", Model);
```

Action Method:

```
public ActionResult SharedView()
{
    var model = ... // 
    return View("~/Areas/<AreaName>/Views/Shared/_SharedView.cshtml", model);
}
```

Comment: This is my current implementation, but this is not a solution. I've several shared views like the profile so this isn't something for the long run.

Comment: Did you set `[Area("<AreaName>")]` for action or controller?

Comment: For me it works as expected. It uses the layout in the area's _viewstart.

Comment: Do you also use different layout's? To be sure i just created a new project and tried it again, but still it keeps the layout of the base _viewstart and not the ones from the area's

Comment: Yes, i use different layout for each area.

Comment: What version of asp.net core are you using, because whatever I try to do, i can't make it work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116133/discussion-between-adem-caglin-and-tom-droste).